# Recovery of Standard Errors of Random Effects in Lmer

Tags: confidence-interval, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme

I'm analysing data with a nested structure with the `lmer`-function of the `lme4` package in R. I'm interested in the estimation of the confidence intervals of the random effects (is the score of class1 higher than class2 nested within school A).

I found very small standard errors using `ranef(mod, postVar = TRUE)`, that I did not expect. With a quick simulation study I found the following results:

```
library(lme4); library(plyr)
   N <- seq(100, 10000, by = 500)
se_sim <- se_lmer <- rep(NA, length(N))

for(i in 1:length(N))
{  
  n = N[i]
  dat <- data.frame(x = c(rnorm(n, 0, 1), rnorm(n, 1, 1)), y = as.factor(rep(1:2, each = n)))
  sum_dat <- ddply(dat, .(y), summarize, m = mean(x), se = sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))) 
  #se = 1/sqrt(1000)
  se_sim[i] <- sum_dat$se[1]

  mod <- lmer(x ~ 1 + (1|y), data = dat)
  r <- ranef(mod, condVar = TRUE)
  se_lmer[i] <- attr(r[[1]], 'postVar')[1, 1, 1] # ??
}

plot(N,se_sim, type='b')
plot(N,se_lmer, type='b')
plot(se_lmer, se_sim)
```

For $n = 1000$, the se's equal 0.03 (as expected, $1/\sqrt(n)$), but when estimated with the ranef function of `lmer` I get about .001 ($1/n$) Hence, the resulting confidence intervals are too small. The plots indicate that the se from `lmer` need to be squared to get the corresponding estimates.

I'm I missing something here? I could not find any related issues elsewhere.

Comment: I don't get this example. dat$y only has 2 levels -- which is too few for a mixed model.